# How to edit/save a file through Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

This is quite a simple question:

I just need to open a file (this filename is galfit.feedme). I can view the file with view galfit.feedme when I'm in the directory, but I do not know how to edit this file and then save the edit. How do you do that?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Normal text editors are `nano` or `vi`.

For example:

```
root@user:# nano galfit.feedme
```

or

```
root@user:# vi galfit.feedme
```

Answer (score 81):

**For editing use**

```
vi galfit.feedme //if user has file editing permissions
```

or

```
sudo vi galfit.feedme //if user doesn't have file editing permissions
```

**For inserting**

```
Press i //Do required editing
```

**For exiting**

```
Press Esc

    :wq //for exiting and saving
    :q! //for exiting without saving
```

Comment: Remember to restart. I wish you didn't have to.

Answer (score 20):

If you are not root user then, use following commands:

There are two ways to do it -

1.

```
sudo vi path_to_file/file_name
```

> Press Esc and then type below respectively
>
> ```
> :wq //save and exit
> :q! //exit without saving
> ```

2. sudo nano path_to_file/file_name

> When using nano:  after you finish editing press <kbd>**ctrl+x**</kbd> then it will ask save **Y/N**.
>   If you want to save press **Y**, if not press **N**.  And press enter to exit the editor.

Answer (score 6):

Open the file using vi or nano. and then press " i " ,

For save and quit

```
  Enter Esc
```

and write the following command

```
  :wq
```

without save and quit

```
  :q!
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to say anything that hasn't already been said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22909944/19068) except you advise people to use nano where those keyboard commands **won't work**.

Answer (score 4):

Within Nano use <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> to exit if you were wondering