# Cant edit neo4j.properties file on Azure hosted neo4j instance

Tags: ubuntu, azure, neo4j

I am a newby at setting up a VM's on azure to host a neo4j instance, so I found this [presentation](http://de.slideshare.net/neo4j/neo4j-on-azure-step-by-step-22598695) that uses Neo4j-Community-1-8-2 image that one can find in the VM-Depot on Azure.
It all worked fine until I wanted to edit the neo4j.properties file to un-comment the node_auto_index line.
There is no "connect" button like there are for other virtual machines on the Azure management portal.
He showed how to create an endpoint to access the web admin console on port 7474(the default), which works fine but Im a little lost as to how to configure that instance of Neo4j installed on the VM?

Any Ideas as to what I could perhaps do to edit the neo4j properties file?

**EDIT**

Would [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/log-on-a-linux-vm/) help? they use putty to log on, but how would I edit the file through this(very little ubuntu expreiance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images in VM Depot are Linux-based, which require you to connect via ssh. And the link you provided, referencing `putty`, is a good one to work from, as putty runs on Windows and provides an ssh-based terminal for you. When you launched your VM instance, ssh should have been set up for you. Assuming you only have one virtual machine in your cloud service, the port *should* have defaulted to 22, but you can check it in the Azure portal, under the Dashboard for your virtual machine (look at the Quick Glance data on the right).

Ok, assuming you've connected: The neo4j image provided by Neo Technology has its configuration files located in `/etc/neo4j`, including `neo4j.properties`:

[image]

You'll need to use a text-based editor (such as `nano`) to edit the file. I'd suggest you post a separate question for Ubuntu file management (or do a search - I'm guessing you'll find something very useful if you search `edit ubuntu file` (such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535428/how-to-edit-save-a-file-through-ubuntu-terminal)).